Why my adhesion force is increasing when I increase the number of points
Here is my implementation of the adhesion force equation:
function adh = adhesionScheme(o,H, delta, m, n,walls,wallsInt,wallsExt)

% flag whether we have walls or not
confined = 0;
if ~isempty(walls) || ~isempty(wallsInt)
  confined = 1;
end
% flag for whether there are two sets of walls with different
% discretization
diffDiscWalls = 0;
if ~isempty(wallsInt)
  diffDiscWalls = 1;
end

oc = curve;

% Compute x,y coordinates of net repulsive force on each point of each
% vesicle due to all other vesicles and walls
adh = zeros(2*o.N,o.nv);

[ox,oy] = oc.getXY(o.X);

if confined
  if ~diffDiscWalls 
    [xwalls,ywalls] = oc.getXY(walls.X);
    Nbd = walls.N;
    
  else
    [xwallsInt,ywallsInt] = oc.getXY(wallsInt.X);
    NbdInt = wallsInt.N;
    
    [xwallsExt,ywallsExt] = oc.getXY(wallsExt.X);
    NbdExt = wallsExt.N;
  end
end

for k = 1:o.nv  
  adhx = zeros(o.N,1); adhy = zeros(o.N,1);  
  
  [~,arcLen] = oc.arcLengthParameter(ox(:,k),oy(:,k));
  hmax = max(diff(arcLen));
  
  notk = [(1:k-1) (k+1:o.nv)];
  notk_ox = ox(:,notk);
  notk_oy = oy(:,notk);

  
  for j = 1 : o.N
    if o.nv ~= 1  
        % Find the distances to each point on a vesicle 
        dist = ((ox(j,k) - notk_ox).^2 + ...
            (oy(j,k) - notk_oy).^2).^0.5;

        dF = (delta^(m-n) - dist.^(m-n))./(dist.^(m+2));

        adhx(j) = sum(sum((ox(j,k) - notk_ox).*dF));
        adhy(j) = sum(sum((oy(j,k) - notk_oy).*dF));
    end
    if confined
      etaWalls = hmax*minDistt;  
      if ~diffDiscWalls  
        dist = ((ox(j,k) - xwalls).^2 + (oy(j,k) - ywalls).^2).^0.5;
        
        % Stiffness l^2
        dF = (delta.^(m-n) - dist.^(m-n))./dist.^(m+2);
        

        wallAdhx = sum(sum((ox(j,k)-xwalls).*dF)); % why there is multiplication by 2?????
        wallAdhy = sum(sum((oy(j,k)-ywalls).*dF)); % Because We calculate adh differently 
      
        % Repulsion due to wall has to beat repulsion due to vesicles if a
        % vesicle is a sandwich between a vesicle and a wall
        adhx(j) = adhx(j) + wallAdhx;
        adhy(j) = adhy(j) + wallAdhy;
      else
        % Interior walls    
        dist = ((ox(j,k) - xwallsInt).^2 + (oy(j,k) - ywallsInt).^2).^0.5;
        L = floor(etaWalls./dist);
      
        % Stiffness l^2
        dF = (delta.^(m-n) - dist.^(m-n))./dist.^(m+2);
      
        wallIntAdhx = sum(sum((ox(j,k)-xwallsInt).*dF));
        wallIntAdhy = sum(sum((oy(j,k)-ywallsInt).*dF));
        
        % Exterior wall
        dist = ((ox(j,k) - xwallsExt).^2 + (oy(j,k) - ywallsExt).^2).^0.5;
        L = floor(etaWalls./dist);
      
        % Stiffness l^2
        dF = (delta.^(m-n) - dist.^(m-n))./dist.^(m+2);
      
        wallExtAdhx = sum(sum((ox(j,k)-xwallsExt).*dF));
        wallExtAdhy = sum(sum((oy(j,k)-ywallsExt).*dF));
      
        % Repulsion due to wall has to beat repulsion due to vesicles if a
        % vesicle is a sandwich between a vesicle and a wall
        adhx(j) = repx(j) + wallIntAdhx + wallExtAdhx;
        adhy(j) = repy(j) + wallIntAdhy + wallExtAdhy; 
          
      end % diffDiscWalls
    end % confined
  end % o.N
  % Adhesion on the kth vesicle multiplied with Adhesion Constants
  adh(:,k) = -(H * m * delta^n)*[adhx; adhy];
end % o.nv
end % AdhesionScheme


We discussed with my advisor and seemingly there is nothing wrong with my implementation. The main issue is that when I increase the number of points, the adhesion force dramatically increases.
The second issue is that the constant H is supposed to be positive, however this makes the force weak and the vesicles will not adhere. When I use negative H, it works almost perfectly as the results from the literature.
I tried adjusting the value by using 32 points as my base as shown below:
  adj_factor = (o.N / 32);
  adh(:,k) = -(H * m * delta^n)*[adhx; adhy]/ adj_factor;

below is just debugging lines to see how the force changes every time I run my code.
disp('Total adhesion force on the  first vesicle:');
disp(norm(adh(:,1)));
disp('\n');
total_points = o.N * o.nv;
normalized_adh = adh / total_points;
disp('Normalized adhesion force per point:');
disp(norm(normalized_adh));


please supply the literature reference where you got the formula, thanks

Hydrodynamics and rheology of a vesicle doublet suspension, https://arxiv.org/abs/1902.05775

try with this line : adhx = zeros(o.N,1); adhy = zeros(o.N,1); outside all loops. As for the sign, it may be another sign changes, tracking it may be time consuming so leave to solve it after solving the core problem

I will try it, but these two variables are only there to store the forces of every point on the nth vesicle and they should be reset to zero after  we finish looping over the nth vesicle. Don`t you think that if it is outside the loop it will even make the force even greater since it has n1+ n2?

I write  "adhx = zeros(o.N,1); adhy = zeros(o.N,1);" outside all loops but still the same problem, :(

I feel like the problem is in the double sum it for some reason

Could you provide a test example with expected outputs, so we can call this function? Besides, Matlab detects some unused variables (Nbd,NbdInt,NbdExt and L) that you should comment if not needed for the time being.

When you approximated the integral over γk by a Riemann sum, didn't you forget the dSy?
Then, increasing the number of points will decrease the size of the dSy associated to each point, which should counterbalance the increase in adhesion force.
